# Cannot access a disposed object. System.Net.Http.StreamContent

Tags: .net

I'm getting a weird, transient, hard-to-track-down, production-only error that the StreamContent for a request has been disposed.  The error occurs on `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`.

I use Autofac and I tried to register HttpClientFactory and use that injected into my class and that did not fix the issue.

What I think is causing this is some kind of gross race condition deep in the library because I'm really hammering these requests out hard and fast.

Looping 20 times with 1 second delays because Carfax can take some time to collect all the data you need.  20 seconds being a timeout, we're never gonna get the info.  And that happens every time someone looks up a VIN on our site which could be as many as 20 simultaneous requests to our server and thus as many as 400 outgoing requests to Carfax using the same code.

The first code block here loops with 1 second delays (starting with an initial 1-second delay because they never have the data right away).  The second block is where the error occurs.

```
private async Task<SingleVinCheck> RequestCarfaxSingleVinCheck(int flaggingRequestId, string vin)
{
    SingleVinCheck singleVinCheck;

    var iRetry = 0;

    do
    {
        if(++iRetry > MaxRetries)
        {
            throw new Exception("Carfax SingleVinCheck failed after " + MaxRetries + " retries. Vin: " + vin + ", FlaggingRequestId: " + flaggingRequestId);
        }
        await Task.Delay(singleVinCheckDelay);

        var singleVinCheckResponseJson = await CarfaxHttpRequest("SingleVinCheck", new NameValueCollection()
        {
            { "FlaggingRequestId", flaggingRequestId.ToString() }
        });

        singleVinCheck = DeserializeSingleVinCheck(singleVinCheckResponseJson);
    } while (singleVinCheck.SingleVinResponseVin == null);

    return singleVinCheck;
}
```

```
private async Task<string> CarfaxHttpRequest(string method, NameValueCollection parameters)
{
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("WebServiceToken", WebServiceToken);
    var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    foreach (string parameterKey in parameters.Keys)
    {
        queryString.Add(parameterKey, parameters[parameterKey]);
    }

    queryString.Add("ThirdPartyKey", ThirdPartyKey);

    var response =
        await httpClient.GetAsync("https://flaggingapi.carfax.ca/VinScan/" + method + "?" + queryString);
    try
    {
        /*** error here ***/
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        var carfaxErrorText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception("Carfax request failed for query: " + queryString + " - Carfax error:" + carfaxErrorText, e);
    }

    var readAsStringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return readAsStringAsync;
}
```